# how to fix "Reference to 'kCGLineCapRound' is ambiguous" error in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

This is the code and I am receiving the error that:  Reference to 'kCGLineCapRound' is ambiguous

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx,kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, location.x, location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    location = currentLocation;
}
```

I don't know how to get rid of this error, any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search your project for kCGLineCapRound and decide which one you want to use.

Comment: What do you mean by decide which one to use?

Comment: I mean there is more than one declared.  Decide which one you want.  Then qualify the reference appropriately.  (Or don't include the .h file of the one you *don't* want, if that's possible.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add CoreGraphics.framework to you project.

http://docs.millennialmedia.com/iOS-SDK/iOSAddingFrameworks.html

Comment: Hmm, try `COREGRAPHICS_H_.kCGLineCapRound` instead.  Also try adding `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to the top of your .m file.

Comment: where do i put the COREGRAPHICS_H_.kCGLineCapRound?